# Unpack wsdl schema from dependencies in Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I've got the following plugin configuration in a Maven (for now) project:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>**/*.xsd,**/*.wsdl</includes>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/schema</outputDirectory>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.someCompany.someTeam.someProject</groupId>
                        <artifactId>someProject-wsdl</artifactId>
                    </artifactItem>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.someCompany</groupId>
                        <artifactId>someCompany-xsd</artifactId>
                    </artifactItem>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.someCompany.someTeam</groupId>
                        <artifactId>common-schema</artifactId>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately, I can't find something similar in Gradle. The only thing I've found is creating a task, loading artifacts as zip files (specifying the whole path to the artifact) and then unzip it.

Is there any other alternative? Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way, that is closer to Gradle best practices:

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}

configurations {
  xsdSources { // Defined a custom configuration
    transitive = false // Not interested in transitive dependencies here
  }
}

dependencies {
  xsdSources "com.someCompany.someTeam.someProject:someProject-wsdl:$someVersion"
  xsdSources "com.someCompany.someTeam:otherArtifact:$otherVersion"
}

task copyWsdlFromArtifacts(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.xsdSources.files.collect { zipTree(it)}
  into "$buildDir/schema"
  include '**/*.xsd', '**/*.wsdl'
  includeEmptyDirs = false
}
```

The benefit is that there is a clear split between where the files are coming from (`repositories`), which files (`dependencies`) and what to do with them (`task` definition).

Comment: that is what they recommended me on Gradle forum:) haven't managed to edit the asnwer

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I ended up with the following task:

```
task copyWsdlFromArtifacts(type: Copy) {
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    def mavenLocalRepositoryUrl = repositories.mavenLocal().url
    [
        "${mavenLocalRepositoryUrl}/com/someCompany/someTeam/someArtifact/${someVersion}/someArtifact-${someVersion}.jar",
        "${mavenLocalRepositoryUrl}/com/someCompany/someTeam/otherArtifact/${otherVersion}/otherArtifact-${otherVersion}.jar"
    ].each { artifact ->
        from(zipTree(artifact))
        into "$buildDir/schema/"
        include '**/*.xsd', '**/*.wsdl'
    }
}
```

Hope it help someone